# Twitter API: Following a user's use of a hashtag?

Tags: api, twitter

I am trying to write a little application to display the most recent tweet from a predetermined single account that use certain hashtag for an event.

Currently I am using the search api like this:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23'. $hashtag .'%20from%3A'. $userhandle .'&rpp=1&result_type=recent
```

But I can only hit this once every 60 seconds and I would ideally like this to be more up to date. I have tried the streaming api, but the url below gets me all the user's tweets, every tweet mentioning the user, and every tweet using the hashtag. Not the nice little cross-section I want.

```
https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json?follow='. $userhandle .'&track=%23'. $hashtag
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the hashtagged tweets from one account only, in a format/frequency more like the streaming api?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is not a way to get this sort of live feed. I ended up doing semi-frequent updates with the older method.